# Capture array index using jq

Tags: arrays, json, shell, jq

With the data

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "id": "id1",
    "ip": "10.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "id": "id2",
    "ip": "10.1.0.0"
  }
]
```

I am trying to capture some fields with the array index

```
instances = ( $( echo $data | jq -r '.[] | ("{something to capture index}" + "." + .name + "~" + .id)' ) )
```

Expected output

```
1.test1~id1
2.test2~id2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `to_entries` generates a `.key`, add `1` to that to get the desired "index"
- Use string manipulation (`\()`) to prevent an '`"" + "" + ""`' spam

```
to_entries[] | "\(.key + 1).\(.value.name)~\(.value.id)"
```

---

```sh
jq --raw-output 'to_entries[] | "\(.key + 1).\(.value.name)~\(.value.id)"'
```

```
1.test1~id1
2.test2~id2
```

---

#### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_aIIRvJTGM)